# Get recyvlerview position without implement onClick on viewholder?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a adapter to my recyclerView. On my Activity control who button is presed.

```
        mProductTerminalNodeAdapter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                switch (v.getId()){
                    case R.id.btnLess:
                        Log.i("","btnLess");
                        break;
                    case R.id.btnPlus:
                        Log.i("","btnPlus");
                        break;
                    case R.id.btnAddProduct:
                        Log.i("","btnAddProduct");
                        break;
                    case R.id.ivTerminalNodeList:
                        Log.i("","
                        break;
                }
```

But I tried to get the click position but can't do it. I have to implement onClick on my ViewHolder? I have to use both onClick?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

override the get view method to get current position

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    int mPosition=position;
    }
```